# trying to load mp3 on jframe tile game

Tags: java, audio, jframe, javasound, game-development

I am making a player based tile game and I want to add music to the background of the GameState. However, when I upload the Sound class:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class Sound {

public static void music() {

    try{
        File file = new File("resources/bracho.mp3");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        try{
        Player player = new Player(bis);
        player.play();
        }
        catch(JavaLayerException e){

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){

    }       
} 
}
```

and this is the init() method:

```
    private void initilization() {
    frame = new Frame(title, width, height);
    frame.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyM); 
    Assets.initilization();

    screenMover = new MoveScreen(this,1,1);
    handler = new Handler(this);

    boardState = new BoardState(handler);
    mainMenuState = new MainMenuState(handler);
    settingsState = new SettingsState(handler);

    State.setState(boardState);

    Sound.music();
}
```

The sound does work, however none of the gui is painted onto the screen it's just the music and the music works fine. So at first I thought the problem was that the music file was too large so I shrunk the file to 500kb and still had a problem. Then I made it multi-threaded and it still had the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: update: after the song ends the entire game loads and works it seems that the program is waiting for the clip to end and then perform the next task. How do I fix this?

Comment: You might get better response (both in the app. & in replies) by using the `Clip` from Java Sound..

Comment: Let's see you multithreadeing attempt. The sound loading and playback should be on its own thread.